# 400 bad request after URL encoding

Tags: java, rest, postman

I am consuming REST web services in my java code. Before make call to Rest web service I am encoding my query parameters by **java.net.URLEncoder**

But by request is getting failed by 400 bad request exception

URL before encoding : `host?limit=200&filter=published ge "2017-12-15T16:50:34.034Z" and (action.objectType eq "core.user_group_member.user_add" or action.objectType eq "core.user_group_member.user_remove")`

URL after decoding : `%3Flimit%3D200%26filter%3Dpublished%20ge%20%222017-12-15T16%3A50%3A34.034Z%22%20and%20%28action.objectType%20eq%20%22core.user_group_member.user_add%22%20or%20action.objectType%20eq%20%22core.user_group_member.user_remove%22%29`

I am tried same from postman rest client tool there also without encoded url is working and encoded url failed with 400 bad request error.

Comment: You need to URL encode the values, not the whole URL.

Comment: yes I have encoded only query string  from ? character

Comment: Yes, I said values, not the whole query string.

Comment: In Postman, what format are you using for the body? (form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, or binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"limit=200&filter=" doesn't need to be coded.

Answer (score 0):

In [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests) you need to encode manually relevant parameters' **values** as follows:

> Right click on a piece of selected text, and select “EncodeURIComponent” to manually encode the parameter value.

Comment: Same issue before encoding I am getting proper response after encoding 400 bad request

Comment: Did you remove your previous encoding?